# Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames - error while making https request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node.js library called urllib (https://github.com/node-modules/urllib) to make http requests. But when I try to run the code I am getting below error:

```
Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames
at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1379:23)
at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
```

After my research, I found out that I need to add an option called `rejectUnauthorized:false`. So I added same using below code:

```
urllib.request(urlToCall,  { rejectUnauthorized:false  }, function (err, data, response) {
   if(err) {
       throw err;
   }
});
```

But still I get the same error. Can anyone please guide me how to resolve this error? Since I am beginner to node and this error looks very strange to me, by the way I am using Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS OS.

Comment: The docs for `rejectUnauthorized` indicate that it is used for servers, not clients and is only useful in conjunction with `requestCert`.  http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurepair_credentials_isserver_requestcert_rejectunauthorized

Comment: @Brandon, yes I am using it against server only. But it looks very strange I am struggling to resolve this error.

Comment: `rejectUnauthorized` can be used by TLS clients.

Comment: Ok, but how do I get rid of that error? @mscdex

Comment: Try process of elimination: use the built-in http.request() instead of a third party module and see if it still happens.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but lot of code has happened over this code so I think it would be difficult to change at this time, I think maybe my syntax is wrong. But not sure.